# Formulating a model for three stage nested ANOVA in R

Tags: r, nested, anova, posthoc

I have the following data structure from an experiment:

Level 1: **Media**       - *Medium 1* vs *Medium 2* 
Level 2: **Treatment type** - *Mono treatments* vs *Switching treatments*  
Level 3: **Treatment**      - *No drug*, *Drug A* and *Drug B* in the *Mono treatments* group and *Switching betwenn Drug A and B*  in the Switching treatments group

I wanted to compare the effect of different treatments on bacterial growth. These treatments are grouped by treatment type. The effect on growth of bacteria of these treatments was tested in two different media. As I understand it, Treatment is nested in Treatment Type which in turn is nested in medium giving me a three stage nested design. All the factors are fixed factors

I wish to analyse this with an ANOVA. That is because my data is neither normally distributed nor homoscedastic and I thus wish to use a randomisation test with the F statistic. Although I found plenty of information on how to write the model for a two stage nested design using the aov() command I cannot seem to find anything about what the command will look like with a three stage nested design like mine. I would be grateful if you guys could help! I think it might go something like

```
aov( OD ~ Media/Treatment type/Treatment, data = data)
```

Since my design is also unbalanced I would add the anova() wrapper to get

```
anova(aov( OD ~ Media/Treatment type/Treatment, data = data))
```

Any suggestions on how to do post hoc tests is also appreciated!

Comment: Okay, so using the command I wrote works out and gives me an ANOVA table with the expected output. However I also get the message 'Note: model has aliased coefficients sums of squares computed by model comparison'. I have a nested model so I would expect that some observations are more similar than others but I do not know how to proceed now.

Comment: I tried the vif(mod) to see which variables are having a high VIF but it shows the message 'there are higher-order terms (interactions) in this model
consider setting terms = 'marginal' or 'high-order'; see ?vif
Error in R[subs, subs] : subscript out of bounds' Any idea what is happening and what to do about it?